# Background fetch What time runs out?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know what the actual device will occur when the backgroundfetch mode

For example, the following code:

Step 1: Enable capabilities "background fetch"

Step2 : Setup AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

    return true;





}
```

Step 3: Register application event in AppDelegate.swift, to register completion handler

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    println("Complete");

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)



    getData();



}



func getData() -> Void{

    var url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=xxxxxx&limit=20";

    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url));



    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request,queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {

        (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var moviesResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary;

        var movies: [NSDictionary]=[];

        movies = moviesResult["movies"] as [NSDictionary];

        var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

        localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"

        localNotification.alertBody = "Movie Count : \(movies.count)"

        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

    }





}
```

When the getdata function executed ?

Have time the program is fully closed,

Always running?

Answer (score 1):

Apple don't give any guarantees as to how often the background fetch executes. It depends on many things, including the current state of the phone (i.e., are you on WiFi or cellular, strong/weak signal, what other apps are doing, how often your app returns new data, etc.) and settings (it doesn't run when in Low Power Mode for instance). It will run as frequently as Apple thinks it makes sense.

If you think that they're making the wrong judgement call, you'll need to use another mechanism to trigger your getData method.

Comment: thanks dear friend
I've written an HTTP connection and I receive information(post method).I need the information in the background to be checked and, if necessary, warn the program. in the other words i need The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network.
To do this you What do you recommend?

Comment: Sure. You asked how often the background fetch runs; that's what I answered.